# Is [ ] also a declarator (when used in parameter declaration) in C?

Tags: c, function-declaration

**6.7.6 Declarators** says

> ***Each declarator declares one identifier**, and asserts that when an operand of the same
>   form as the declarator appears in an expression, it designates a function or object with the
>   scope, storage duration, and type indicated by the declaration specifiers.*

And also states about *syntax* of parameter:

```
parameter-declaration:
    declaration-specifiers declarator
    declaration-specifiers abstract-declarator(opt)
```

For the given function prototype

```
int f( int a[], int n);
```

`int a[]` declares a parameter with declarator `a[]` which declares an identifier `a`.

---

While in case of

```
int f( int [], int n);
```

`int []` declares parameter is an *array of int* with no identifier.
**Is `[]` also a declarator ?** ( I think no because it doesn't declare an identifier but syntax for parameter says it is!)

Comment: **Each declarator declares one identifier**. `[]` is an *abstract declarator*.

Comment: @n.m.; What is an abstract declarator? I was jus thinking about that!

Comment: @n.m.; Thanks. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/b198y5xs(v=vs.80).aspx) it is.

Comment: You have quoted a production that mentions it. The definition should be somewhere around 6.7.7 I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the identifier-less parameter declaration, you have an *abstract declarator*.  That is, the `[]` in `int f(int [], int n)` is an abstract declarator for the array.  You can find more in sections §6.7.6 **Declarators** and §6.7.7 **Type names** in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (the C11 standard).