# Declarators semantics in C99

Tags: c, c99, c11

According to the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.7.5 §2,

> Each declarator declares one identifier, and asserts that **when an operand of the same
>   form as the declarator appears in an expression**, it designates a function or object with the
>   scope, storage duration, and type indicated by the declaration specifiers.

I have no idea why an expression suddenly shows up in the declarators semantics. Would you give me some examples that can help me understand the meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have the declaration

```
int foo[42];
```

The declarator part is `foo[42]`. Whenever something of same form (ie `foo` followed by `[` followed by an expression followed by `]`) appears within an expression (and the delaration is in scope), the type of that sub-expression will be of the declared type `int`.

To put it another way: As far as syntax goes, a declaration like

```
int *bar;
```

does *not* declare `bar` to be of type `int *`, but instead declares `*foo` to be of type `int`.

For a more involved example, take the declaration

```
float (*op[42])(float, float);
```

In an expression, an operand of same form could look like this

```
c = (*op[i])(a, b);
```

According to the quotation, the right-hand side would have type `float`.

This implies that

```
*op[i]
```

must have function type (we ignore the fact that function designators decay to corresponding pointer types and function invocation via postfix `()` actually works on pointers, not designators).

This in turn implies that

```
op[i]
```

must denote a function pointer and we finally arrive at

```
op
```

denoting an array of function pointers as that's what we can apply postfix `[]` on and get back the correct type.

Fun, isn't it ;)

Comment: Your examples are so easy to understand. Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Answer (score 5):

Say you declare:

```
static int const i, j, k;
```

That is same as:

```
static int const i;
static int const j;
static int const k;
```

The declarator specifer, `static int const` is applied to all the identifiers.

You can also extend that logic to functions and function pointers.

```
static int i, (*fun1)(void), fun2(void);
```

which is same as:

```
static int i;
static int (*fun1)(void);
static int fun2(void);
```

As far as the *appears in an expression* part goes, there is some commentary at http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.5.pdf. It says:

> **Semantics**
>
> Each declarator declares one identifier, and asserts that when an operand of the same form as the declarator appears in an expression, it designates a function or object with the scope, storage duration, and type indicated by the declaration specifiers.
>
> **Commentary**
>
> The form of an identifier in an expression is likely to be the same as that in the declarator. For instance, the declarator * x will have this form in an expression when the value pointed to by x is required and the declarator y[2] will have this form in an expression when an element of the array y is referred to. It is the declarator portion of a declaration that declares the identifier. There is a special kind of declarator, an abstract-declarator, which does not declare an identifier

I interpret the above to mean:

If you declare:

```
int *x;
```

and use `*x` in an expression, the type of `*x` is `int`.

If you declare

```
static int const *x;
```

and use `*x` in an expression, the type of `*x` is `static int const`.

**Additional references**

[Static Variable Declaration (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658907/static-variable-declaration-c)

[Is [ ] also a declarator (when used in parameter declaration) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793829/is-also-a-declarator-when-used-in-parameter-declaration-in-c)

[C -- Accessing a non-const through const declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051969/c-accessing-a-non-const-through-const-declaration)

Comment: I don't see any expressions in your examples. How are these connected to expressions?

Answer (score 0):

All that's saying is, given a declaration like

```
const int a = 5; // declaration
```

then the *operand* `a` in an expression like

```
x = a + b
```

within the same scope has type `const int`.

Comment: this is the trivial example because the declarator is just an identifier